# SQLite creating uploading and managing an online database

Tags: sql, database

First of all let me just note that i'm a newbie in the field.

What i'm trying to do is create an online DB for my android application.

I'v been looking for the net for tutorials and could not find any.

What I want to learn is:

1. are there any sites that host sqlite databases
2. how do i create an sqlite database?
3. how do i upload the DB to the website
4. how to i communicate with the DB after it's online.

Any help would more help here guys, please.

thank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me answer all your questions.

1) SQLite is not a traditional SQL Database, no server is necessary there is only a file.

2) A great tutorial by Lars Vogel explains almost all concepts of sqlite in android.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

3) You can upload the sqlite database to a webserver as a regular file, but with only backup intents this is plausible.

4) Again there is no server; just a file on storage unit, such as harddisk or memory.

I strongly recommend to read article I linked above.

Comment: Can this SQLite db file be downloaded and used as the database for an Android application? and can it also be generated from SQL server